# Swift Nil Exception on URL

Tags: swift, url, null, optional-parameters

I’m new to Swift and writing an app that reads data from a scanner then posts it to a web page.  I am taking the data from a text edit field on my main storyboard for now and when I press a lookup button to trigger the following code it throws the below exception.  I set a break point and checked the value of temp prior to its use in the URL and its colored in correctly (not nil).   If I type into the edit field then the code works fine from then on; opens the page even if I delete the contents of the edit field using the clear icon (x).

I’m at a loss to understand which variable is nil and how to correct or protect the code.  Any help would be appreciated.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func setStatus(_ status: String)
{
    statusLabel.text = status
}

func processRead(_ data: String?)
{
    if (data != nil)
    {
        var temp: String = data!
        setStatus(temp)

        temp = "foo.com?data=" + temp

        let url: URL = URL(string: temp)!      //  <<<< THROWS EXCEPTION / BREAK POINT 
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

UPDATE -- Corrected code --

```
func setStatus(_ status: String)
{
    statusLabel.text = status
}


func processRead(_ data: String?)
{
    if (data != nil && !data!.isEmpty)
    {
        let temp = "https://foo.com/data=" + data!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!);
        if let url = URL(string: temp)
        {
            setStatus(data!)
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
        else
        {
            print("Bad URL: " + temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: I read that post but I don't see what is nil.  temp contains a valid URL string

Comment: `URL(string: temp)` must be evaluating to `nil`. Check the documentation for that function to see in what cases it returns `nil`. I'm going to guess that means that the address you're giving it isn't a valid URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that when initizlizing the `URL` object with the temp string, it can't successfully convert the string into a URL. As URL initializer `init?(string: String)` is an optional initializer it can return nil if there is an error converting the sting into an URL. Try adding "https://" to you string.

```
 temp = "https://foo.com?data=" + temp
```

Comment: You want `https` unless you want to deal with App Transport Security.

Comment: Tried that but same problem.  You are on the right track, it can't convert the string to a valid URL.

Comment: Our web system automatically redirects all http traffic to https.

Answer (score 3):

There is a possibility that `temp` contains some characters that are invalid in the query part of a URL. This makes the whole string not a valid URL, so `URL.init` returns nil. You need to escape those characters by calling `addingPercentEncoding`:

```
URL(string: "foo.com?data=" + temp.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!)
```

Comment: While this may be needed, the immediate problem is the lack of a scheme.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried the code and it successfully creates a `URL`, so schemes are optional, no?

Comment: While this might be needed, this wont encode query params correctly when it contains ? or & or =.

Comment: It is odd that this code results in a non-nil URL despite the lack of URL scheme.

Comment: The above worked perfectly.  Perhaps the edit field returns something with unacceptable characters for a URL because it only happens prior to touching into the edit field and a bad URL string throws an exception even though its non-nil, non-blank. Thanks for the quick help.  All is well for now.

Comment: So I could do this to protect the code:  
           let url: URL? = URL(string: temp)
            
            if (url != nil)
            {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL("foo.com/data=" + temp)!)
            }
        }

Comment: @zappullae The proper way is `if let url = URL(string: temp) { UIApplication.shared.openURL(url) } else { print("bad url") }`.